# How do I draw a line behind an animation?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I am trying to add a line behind an element (plane svg) which is moved around in a keyframe animation. I want the line to follow its path as the plane moves and also leave a trace so that the plane's whole path can be seen. The direction and magnitude of where the plane moves is random and is changed in a `--crash-point` variable that is randomly assigned a value using javascript (`Math.random()`). I would like it to look like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSMAu.png).

I have tried using animateMotion but I am not sure if it would allow me to accomplish this. I also have not been able to find an examples of this being done in a codepen or something similar.

How do I do this?

App.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import plane from "./assets/plane.svg";

function App() {
    const planeRef = useRef();
    const containerRef = useRef();
    const animationContainerRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
            "--crash-point",
            `${Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 - 200 + 1)) + 200}px`,
            // Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min,
            console.log(
                document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue("crash-point"),
            ),
        );
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="big-container">
                <div
                    className="animation-container shift-container-x"
                    ref={animationContainerRef}
                >
                    <div
                        ref={containerRef}
                        className="img-container"
                        onAnimationEnd={() => {
                            containerRef.current.classList.add("crash");
                            animationContainerRef.current.classList.add(
                                "crash-container",
                            );
                        }}
                    >
                        <img ref={planeRef} src={plane} alt="" />
                        // this line element should follow the plane svg and leave a trace
                        <div className="line"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
html {
    --crash-point: 200px;
}

.big-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 5rem;
    margin-top: 700px;
    background: url(./assets/dot.svg) space center;
    background: transparent;
}

.animation-container {
    border: 1px solid purple;
    /* position: relative; */
    position: absolute;
    height: 2500px;
    width: 2000px;
    bottom: -25rem;
    background: url(./assets/white-dots.jpg) repeat center;
    background-size: 15%;
    z-index: -100;
    animation: shiftContainerX 5s ease-in-out;
}

.crash-container {
    animation: crashContainer 5s ease-in-out;
}

.img-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 25rem;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    animation: moveDiagonal 5s ease-in-out;
    /* border: 1px solid blue; */
    z-index: 999;
}

.crash {
    animation: crash 5s ease-in-out;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50px;
    object-fit: contain;
    height: 50px;
    animation: moveX 10s;
    /* border: 1px solid; */
    text-align: left;
}

@keyframes moveDiagonal {
    100% {
        transform: translate(
            var(--crash-point),
            calc(var(--crash-point) * -1.5)
        );
        /* transform: translate(200px, -300px); */
    }
}

@keyframes crash {
    0% {
        transform: translate(
            var(--crash-point),
            calc(var(--crash-point) * -1.5)
        );
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(var(--crash-point), calc(var(--crash-point) / 2));
        /* transform:translate(200px, 100px); */
    }
}

@keyframes moveX {
    100% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--crash-point) / 1.5));
    }
}

@keyframes shiftContainerX {
    100% {
        transform: translate(
            calc(var(--crash-point) / -1.25),
            calc(var(--crash-point) / 1.5)
        );
    }
}

@keyframes crashContainer {
    0% {
        transform: translate(
            calc(var(--crash-point) / -1.25),
            calc(var(--crash-point) / 1.5)
        );
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(
            calc(var(--crash-point) / -1.25),
            calc(var(--crash-point) / -1.5)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: In the image it looks like a curve. How is that curve calculated? Is the plain moving i a straight line or how is the relationship between line and plain?

Comment: @chrwahl The `moveDiagonal` keyframe animation moves the **img-container** (the parent div of the plane svg) in a diagonal and the `moveX` keyframe animation moves the actual plane element to the right at the same time, which causes a slight bend and makes it into a curve.

Comment: Before knowing how to do it in react you may need to have an idea of what you want to do. Before knowing how to do it when the direction and magnitude of where the plane moves is random you may want to know how to do it when you have a fixed path. Next you may want to know how to change the fixed path to a random one. **I can show you how to do it with animateMotion** on a fixed path. You may also think how do you intend to change the path to a random one. But this may be another question.

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks I would love for you to show me how to do it with animateMotion on a fixed path?

Answer (score 1):

In the following example the plain is following a circular path but you can change the d attribute to something else. Please observe that the point of the plain that is following the path is in the origin of the svg canvas (x:0,y:0)

```css
svg{width:90vh;border:solid;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-20 -20 180 180" >
  <path id="path" d="M0,70 a70,70 0 1, 0 0,-1 z" fill="none" stroke="red" >
  </path>
  <path fill="none" stroke="blue" d="M0,0l3.5,1v-1.5l-2,-1.5v-5.5l8,2.5l0,0v-2l-8,-5v-5.5c0,-0.83,-0.67,-1.5,-1.5,-1.5s-1.5,0.67,-1.5,1.5v5.5l-8,5v2l8,-2.5v5.5l-2,1.5v1.5l3.5,-1z" transform="rotate(90)">
    <animateMotion dur="10s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#path"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </path>
</svg>
```

In order to make the line to follow the plane I will use a stroke-dasharray attribute for the red path.

> The stroke-dasharray attribute is a presentation attribute defining the pattern of dashes and gaps used to paint the outline of the shape;

For example if the `stroke-dasharray = "5 2"` you will have dashes of 5 units followed by gaps of 2 units.

In order to make the red path follow the plane I will use `stroke-dasharray="0 440"` meaning that I will have dashes of 0 units followed by a very long gap of 440 units. The total length of the path is 440. In this case no dash is visible.

I will animate the `stroke-dasharray` attribute from "0 440" to "440 0". The end value of "440 0" will draw a very long dash, as long as the path, and no gap. Also if the duration for the animateMotion is dur="10s" I will use the same duration for the `stroke-dasharray` animation making the stroke grow with the same speed  as the speed of the plain:

```css
svg{width:90vh;border:solid;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-20 -20 180 180" width="240">
  <path id="path" d="M0,70 a70,70 0 1, 0 0,-1 z" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-dasharray="0 440">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" to="440 0" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
  <path fill="none" stroke="blue" d="M0,0l3.5,1v-1.5l-2,-1.5v-5.5l8,2.5l0,0v-2l-8,-5v-5.5c0,-0.83,-0.67,-1.5,-1.5,-1.5s-1.5,0.67,-1.5,1.5v5.5l-8,5v2l8,-2.5v5.5l-2,1.5v1.5l3.5,-1z" transform="rotate(90)">

    <animateMotion dur="10s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#path"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </path>
</svg>
```

**Observation**: when changing the circular path with your own path do not forget to change the value for the stroke-dasharray. Where now is 440 you will need to use the calculated length of the new path. In JavaScript you can do it using the `getTotalLength()` method.